# How do you automate fixing formatting errors found by ament_cpplint?

Tags: ros2, rclcpp

I'm working on a PR for rclcpp, and when I run the tests, I get formatting errors about white space from cpplint. Is there any automated way to fix these? Here is an example:

```
- rclcpp.cpplint whitespace/comments [2] (/home/tyler/code/ws_ros2/src/rclcpp/rclcpp/include/rclcpp/subscription_options.hpp:188)
  <<< failure message
    At least two spaces is best between code and comments
  >>>
```

Comment: what does this have to do with robotics? ... ensure that you format your code properly ... comments are not part of the code ... separate them by a wide margin

Comment: I'm not asking what the rule is but if there is automated tooling for this.

On if this is relevant to robotics I had that same thought so I posted here and was told yes, this is the right place for this question: https://discourse.ros.org/t/planned-migration-of-ros-answers-and-gazebo-answers-to-robotics-stack-exchange/28068/23

Answer (score 3):

Recently, I've had some success running `ament_uncrustify --reformat` for fixing issues found by `ament_cpplint`, since these tools (largely) agree.

Not the answer I like, but `ament_cpplint` has no similar option unfortunately.

Comment: These errors showed up after running uncrustify. For me to use a formatting tool on my project table-stakes is that it can format the files itself according to its rule set. I was hoping that cpplint had some hidden auto-format feature I couldn't find.

Comment: Hmm, too bad. I also hoped for the same.

Comment: There's no auto-support for Cpplint, I do the same thing @loy suggested. I run uncrustify to resolve the bulk and then cpplint for the rest. Though after a couple of months using these linters you should get to a point where you know the rules and rarely need to fix anything.

Comment: This is a sad state of affairs when `clang-format` is right there.